# What is git doing with "git submodule update" that I get coo-coo error: "outside repository"

Tags: linux, git

I'm getting this rather coo-coo error when using the Vim package manager [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim)'s :PluginUpdate command. On further investigation, I've narrowed the problem down to the `submodule update` operation. Sure enough, if I perform the same git operation as shown in the Vundle log on one of these packages I get:

```
$ pwd
/home/mastershake/xtian/.vim/bundle/closetag.vim
$ ls -al
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  4 xtian xtian 4.0K Apr 11  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 xtian xtian 4.0K Oct 24  2015 ..
drwxr-xr-x  8 xtian xtian 4.0K Oct 31 09:05 .git
drwxr-xr-x  2 xtian xtian 4.0K Apr 11  2015 plugin
-rw-r--r--  1 xtian xtian 1.5K Apr 11  2015 README
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
fatal: /home/mastershake/xtian/Documents.x/Employment.d/Jobs.d: '/home/mastershake/xtian/Documents.x/Employment.d/Jobs.d' is outside repository
```

On further investigation, I discover anywhere I perform this same git operation I get the same error. I say it's coo-coo, because the error has nothing to do with any individual `.git` repo itself.

What's git doing, and how do I fix it?

//UPDATE: Added directory contents to make it clearer what's happening.

Comment: git commands must be run in a git repo (i.e. a directory containing `.git` directory). The error means you ran the git command outside of a git repo.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear. Vundle is a plugin manage for vim which runs git updates for plugins hosted at Github. I also performed the same command in another project with a git repo. The results are the same either way.

Comment: It looks the path to the submodule is weird. Usually a submodule is set by a relative path from its parent's root directory (i.e. closetag.vim). Can you show the contents of `.gitmodules` and `.git/config`?

Comment: It seems there is some [issues about submodules in Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/226#issuecomment-13779066) 
What's more, the problem resolved itself. 
I did a system update (in Archlinux) and git was updated (2.10.1-1 -> 2.10.2-1) and Vim (8.0.0046-2 -> 8.0.0055-1)
And I still don't have submodules in any of my Vundle bundles!